# C programming suites/IDEs

Tags: programming, ide

I know that asking for something like Visual Studio is too much but something that will let me write, debug and compile in a GUI instead of the command line is good enough for me. (Not that I'm lazy, but I don't have time to learn the necessary commands...)

Answer (score 28, accepted):

### Code::Blocks

```
sudo apt install codeblocks
```

[image]

Wikipedia: [Code::Blocks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code::Blocks)

Answer (score 26):

### Geany

Geany is a text editor using the GTK2 toolkit with basic features of an integrated development environment. It was developed to provide a small and fast IDE, which has only a few dependencies from other packages. It supports many filetypes and has some nice features.

To install geany in all currently supported versions of Ubuntu open the terminal and type:

```
sudo apt install geany
```

[image]

Comment: I like geany mostly because its the only free editor that feels most like my favorite non-free editor, SlickEdit.  Searching is a big deal to me, SlickEdit does it best, Geany's not too bad.

Answer (score 26):

### Eclipse

Eclipse with [Eclipse IDE for C/C++ Developers](https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/).

This package includes:

- C/C++ Development Tools
- Git integration for Eclipse

[image]

Regardless of your operating system, you will need to install some Java virtual machine (JVM). You may either install a Java Runtime Environment (JRE), or a Java Development Kit (JDK), depending on what you want to do with Eclipse. If you intend to use Eclipse for Java development, then you should install a JDK. If you aren't planning to use Eclipse for Java development and want to save some disk space, install a JRE.

If you are using Linux, [read this](https://wiki.eclipse.org/IRC_FAQ#I_just_installed_Eclipse_on_Linux.2C_but_it_does_not_start._What_is_the_problem.3F).

Answer (score 18):

### MonoDevelop

If you like Visual Studio, you will certainly like MonoDevelop. You can find it in the Software Center. You can even write .NET apps with it if you want to (like C# as you can see in the screenshot), but I suggest you don't.

To install MonoDevelop in Ubuntu 14.04-16.04 open the terminal and type:

```
sudo apt install monodevelop
```

[image: MonoDevelop]][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j28Ps.png)

Comment: Why do you suggest not to write C# apps ?

Comment: If you are able to write an application in native code, like C or C++, I think it is always better to do so. Using a framework like .NET always has a small impact on performance, so it might be better to avoid it. 
Mono is great to make it easier for porting Windows apps to Linux, but when developing native applications for Linux I personally would rather use open-source technologies.

Comment: leave mono debate out of this please. Mono is Open Source.

Answer (score 16):

### CodeLite

CodeLite is a powerful and lightweight IDE specializing in C, C++, PHP and JavaScript. Its features include:

- Generic support for compilers
- Built-in GDB support
- Database-based Code Completion mechanism
- Syntax highlighting for C/C++, Java, Perl, XML, Makefile, Lua, Diff files,
  PHP, JavaScript, Python, HTML, and ASP
- Text Folding
- Bookmarks
- Find and Replace
- doxygen comment generator

To install CodeLite in all currently supported versions of Ubuntu open the terminal and type:

```
sudo apt install codelite
```

[image]

[CodeLite screenshot gallery](https://codelite.org/gallery.php)

For me CodeLite is the best replacement for Visual Studio.

Answer (score 13):

### NetBeans

Apache NetBeans IDE lets you quickly and easily develop Java desktop, Java EE, and web applications, as well as HTML5 applications with HTML, JavaScript, and CSS. The IDE also provides a great set of tools for PHP and C/C++ developers. To install NetBeans in all currently supported versions of Ubuntu open the terminal and type:

```
sudo snap install netbeans --classic
```

[image]

Comment: Netbeans font is ugly on Ubuntu and that screenshot is from windows ;)

Answer (score 13):

### [vim [image: Install vim]](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/vim)

Vim is also a good choice for writing C programs.

[image]

Comment: Vim without any plugin might not be a good choice for IDE. But with few plugins , it can become a powerful IDE.  I use Ultisnip+clang_complete+supertab+delimate to turn vim into a C/C++ IDE.

Answer (score 12):

### Anjuta

Anjuta is a versatile software development studio featuring a number of advanced programming facilities including project management, application wizard, interactive debugger, source editor, version control, GUI designer, profiler and many more tools. It focuses on providing simple and usable user interface, yet powerful for efficient development.

To install Anjuta in all currently supported versions of Ubuntu open the terminal and type:

```
sudo apt install anjuta
```

[image]

Answer (score 9):

### Emacs

Install emacs-gtk for the version which supports good readable freetype fonts, gtk and other visual goodies.

Emacs allows you to compile and debug inside the GUI. With CEDET package, it has got nice code completion for C and C++ projects. Color theme will give nice themes and syntax coloring for the source code. Emacs can be customized heavily using the e-lisp.

Emacs running with CEDET and color theme showing code completion.

Also refer to [Ubuntu Community Help Wiki for EmacsHowto](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EmacsHowto).

[image: Emacs running with CEDET and color theme]

Comment: [ECB](http://ecb.sf.net/) is an Emacs package that provides the browsing features and side panes that other IDEs have -- check out the [sample screenshots](http://ecb.sourceforge.net/screenshots/) for a visual explanation.

Comment: Also, unlike many IDEs that specialize in one or a few languages, Emacs provides good editing support for [almost anything that has a text format](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/CategoryModes), so you can use it for easier integrated editing all the files that comprise a program distribution.

Answer (score 8):

### KDevelop

I very highly recommend KDevelop. It's a KDE program, but it will work under GNOME. It's like a color explosion. Pretty much every single variable, class, method, language construct, etc. has a different color. Not just local variables one color, global, etc. Every local variable will have a different color from each other one.

It also integrates with cmake extremely well and is generally a great IDE to work with. I really wish there was a Java and/or Python plugin for it.

To install KDevelop in all currently supported versions of Ubuntu open the terminal and type:

```
sudo apt install kdevelop
```

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 6):

### [qtcreator [image: Install qtcreator]](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/qtcreator)

QT Creator is the best C/C++ IDE available for Ubuntu.

> Qt Creator is a cross-platform C++ integrated development environment which is part of the Qt SDK[2]. It includes a visual debugger and an integrated GUI layout and forms designer. The editor's features includes syntax highlighting and autocompletion, but not tabs. Qt Creator uses the C++ compiler from the GNU Compiler Collection on Linux and FreeBSD. On Windows it can use MinGW or MSVC with the default install and can also use cdb when compiled from source.

[image]

Answer (score 5):

## Sublime Text 2

I recommend [Sublime Text 2](http://www.sublimetext.com/2). It is not free but worth every cent.

> Sublime Text 2 may be downloaded and evaluated for free, however a license must be purchased for continued use. There is currently no enforced time limit for the evaluation.

[image]

It features a plethora of useful features and is highly extensible.

Answer (score 4):

### Eclipse

Just for completeness I suggest you take a look at Eclipse. To install Eclipse in all currently supported versions of Ubuntu open the terminal and type:

```
sudo snap install eclipse --classic
```

Eclipse can handle just about any language you like with the right plugin, but in my opinion better options have already been mentioned in this list.

Answer (score 2):

### Anjuta DevStudio

Anjuta IDE for C/C++ and GNOME/Gtk+ applications has features that enable easy debugging, management of code and GUI design by providing a simple and usable user interface. It also integrates with version control systems like CVS, Git or Subversion.

To install Anjuta in all currently supported versions of Ubuntu open the terminal and type:

```
sudo apt install anjuta
```

Answer (score 2):

One more good editor and awarded is [Komodo Edit](http://www.activestate.com/komodo-edit). You can use it with a lot languagies c, c++, python and more. Is free and croos platform.

There is a [Komodo IDE](http://www.activestate.com/komodo-ide) but it is commercial and non-free. You can try it with a trial version.

[image]

[image]