# What is the Best Way to use & practice coding in C language on Ubuntu 12.04?

Tags: programming, language-support, c

I want to learn **C language** . and i would like to know how I can practice it using **Ubuntu 12.04**

Is there any **platform** for it and if so how can I get it? Or can I learn it using the terminal?

Comment: Take a look at [How could I begin C++ programming on Ubuntu?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/36520/how-could-i-begin-c-programming-on-ubuntu)

Comment: You topic is broad and may create discussion. There are many way to use and practice C in Ubuntu. Also I think, there are at least 2 different questions in it.

Comment: this too much thing i confused !! 
i want determinables name or explansion links please !

Comment: ^^^ Now I'm confused? Basic C/C++ programming and fundamentals are the same no matter what OS you use. Maybe you could go to your localc computer bookstore and look at a few books?

Comment: this is perhaps the wrong stackexchange - this would be ontopic (with perhaps much better answers) on the StackOverflow.com SE site.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> **NOTE** : Refer Online resources for C learning tutorials , i am only
>   linking the Tools and Platform available In Ubuntu ,needed for you to
>   begin with C.

To use **C** and **C++** you will need to install the **build-essential** package.

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential
```

You can now compile C and C++ programs with [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) and [g++](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man1/g++.1.html) .

Where  GCC stands for **“GNU Compiler Collection”**. GCC is an integrated distribution of compilers for several major programming languages. These languages currently include **C, C++, Objective-C, Objective-C++, Java, Fortran, Ada, and Go.**

You will find available [Official Programming tools here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Programming) and for [Power Users Programming](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/PowerUsersProgramming)

To help you begin from Ground-Zero refer here for typing your [Fisrt C program and how to compile it](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_program_structure.htm) and another [Example Tutorial using GCC](http://courses.cms.caltech.edu/cs11/material/c/mike/misc/compiling_c.html).

**To begin with** : What you will basically need is an **Editor** from above  , ( try **Gedit** as beginner, there are many to choose from) for **compiling through Command Line**

Or

Directly use **IDE ( Integrated Development Environment)** such as [**Geany**](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/geany/) ,[**Anjuta**](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/anjuta/) or  [**Code::Blocks IDE**](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/natty/codeblocks/).

**Example Using text editor**

[image]

Then in terminal

```
gcc hello.c -o hello1   

./hello1
```

which will give `O/P` like

```
user@host:~/Desktop$ ./hello1
Hello! This is my first C program with Ubuntu 12.04
```

Comment: Great!
thanks for that. but can i have some linke for how to use it ??
i can't distinguish and know what is the GCC OR G++ ?

Comment: i faield to use it ....sorry :)

Comment: anyway thanks brother i will try to use it later maybe iwill know more that will help me :)

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use and practice only C, then you can use the default gcc compiler (*which is installed by default as C compiler on almost every Linux distribution*) . From your question, I suppose you also wanted to use this in terminal. Here I give a simple example of a C program using terminal.

Open a terminal and type `nano hello.c` and Press Enter.

An editor will be opened in terminal. This is nano. Type the following to create a simple C program

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){

    printf("Hello C, I am in Ubuntu\n");
    return 0;
}
```

- Then Press `CTRL`+`O` to write to the file. Then press `CTRL` + `W` to exit nano.
- Then type `gcc -o hello hello.c`. It will compile the `hello.c` file and create an executable with name `hello`.
- Then type `./hello` to see the output of the program.

Note: The details explanation of the program is beyond the scope of the answer.

You can check these link to learn more about gcc compiler and using C in Ubuntu.

#### [gcc online documentation](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/)

#### [gcc manual page](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/jaunty/man1/gcc.1.html)

#### [Learn C online](http://www.learnconline.com/)

#### [C programming tutorial](http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/c-tutorial.html)

Comment: you are Great! 
you read my mind and give what i want .. thanks you .. Good luck

Comment: You can accept this if it helps by clicking on the grey tick mark at the left had side of the answer. Thanks.