# How to compile a c++ program from notepad++?

Tags: compiling, c++

I am running notepad++ through wine. But I am not able to compile a program(specially c++).

Is there any compiler that I could use? What should I do?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu. This question should be asked on http://www.superuser.com because it is off-topic on this site.

Comment: @Alex why should asked on superuser??

Comment: Is the question about compiling C++ source code without leaving Notepad++? If so, you should explicitly specify this.

Answer (score 6):

1. Install **g++** `sudo apt-get install g++`.
2. Open terminal and go to file directory.
3. Fast compiling `g++ filename.cpp` and run **./a.out**.[image]
4. Specify output name `g++ filename.cpp -o filename.out`.
5. If you want to know more about g++ open terminal and write `man g++`.

Comment: thnx..but i need some different compiler ...i dont want to use terminal on compiling

Comment: it's not terminal the compiler now is g++ which is the most used by c++ programmer if you asking for install another tool or IDE install geany, codeblocks ,  eclipse or netbeans

Comment: Runs Linux, doesn't want to use a terminal...  You could learn how to write makefiles, that would prevent you having to write the compiler options over and over.  Though you would still have to invoke make...

Answer (score 4):

Notepad++ is not a compiler and does not contain a compiler.  You must install a separate compiler, then configure Notepad++ to use it.

The [NppExec](https://sourceforge.net/projects/npp-plugins/files/NppExec/) plugin ([docs](http://www.cin.ufpe.br/~aedv/Notepad++Portable/App/Notepad++_ansi/plugins/doc/NppExec_Manual.txt)) can be made to do this.  (I've never done it, so I cannot verify that the following currently works.)  [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2506400/how-to-compile-and-run-c-files-from-within-notepad-using-nppexec-plugin) over on stackoverflow gives detailed instructions to use NppExec to save the current document, and then run it through a perl interpreter.  The (currently) [other answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/790023/559883) here gives an example of passing the source through the g++ compiler (for C++).

Just to be clear:  There is no compiler bundled with Notepad++.  You must install another package to have a compiler.  Once you have done so, you can adapt the above to cause Notepad++ to save your source, invoke the compiler on the source, run the resulting executable (which you might eventually want to make condition on a successful build), and show you its console output.

If you would prefer a complete IDE (instead of a very fancy editor that can be made into an IDE), see [this other question](https://askubuntu.com/q/36520/559883) and its several answers.  Note that these also require installation of a compiler (as a separate package).  Some of these include this requirement via package dependencies, but generally do not -- you will still have to install a compiler.  I might go with the invocation

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential
```

since this will include g++, gcc, libc*-dev, and make.  ([Package build-essential](http://packages.ubuntu.com/precise/build-essential) is intended for building Debian packages, but includes a bare minimum C++ build chain.)