# Is there a Source Insight alternative?

Tags: software-recommendation, programming, development, source-code

I am not a developer, but for my work I trace a lot of codes.  It is actually rather difficult reading other people's code, especially for bigger projects.

Source Insight is a great application that stores all the symbols in a data base, so you can see a new function being called, click on it and see how the function is written.  You can see all the referrer of a object or jump to a caller.  You don't need to break the train of thought and think up shell commands just to find these things every time you ran into a new variable/structure/function from some other files.

I have it running on WINE, but there are little glitches that sometimes gets in the way.

I know people will mention C-scope, I've tried it, but it really isn't the same. So, with so many huge open source projects out there for Ubuntu, are there native tools to help read them efficiently?

EDIT:

Thanks for the suggestions, but does CODE::BLOCKS or CodeLite provide abilities to see the function that the mouse clicked on without jumping to it, so I can see the caller and callee at the same time?

[image]

Comment: which one did you finally use?

Comment: I finally decided to use Trinity plugin in vim, with ctag and cscope....

Answer (score 4):

[Code::Blocks](http://packages.ubuntu.com/codeblocks) might be an option.

Code::Blocks is a free C++ IDE built to meet the most demanding needs of its users. It is designed to be very extensible and fully configurable.

An IDE with all the features a developer need, having a consistent look, feel and operation across platforms.

Built around a plugin framework, Code::Blocks can be extended with plugins. Any kind of functionality can be added by installing/coding a plugin. For instance, compiling and debugging functionality is already provided by plugins!

[image]

<sub>Runs on windows too</sub>
<sub>I'll let someone else post about [codelite](http://www.codelite.org/) and [widestudio](http://www.widestudio.org/EE/index.html) so you can pick one</sub>

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if I correctly understand what you want to do, but basically any IDE can do what you want - Code::Blocks from the other answer is what comes to my mind, too; or [Eclipse](http://www.eclipse.org/).

Since you don't say which language it should be for, I'll refer you to this collection of IDE's for C: [C programing suites/IDEs](https://askubuntu.com/questions/8136/c-programing-suites-ides)

Answer (score 1):

I think what you want is a [Source-Navigator](http://sourcenav.sourceforge.net/)

if you still don't like this, you can wine your source insight.

Answer (score 1):

There is none. No other IDE is as intuitive as source insight and if that would be they will be licensed and paid.

Answer (score 0):

There is [sourcetrail](https://www.sourcetrail.com) : Sourcetrail is a cross-platform source explorer for C, C++, Java and Python.