# Problem setting up Environment for 'make' command execution

Tags: command-line, bash, development, arm

I am trying to set up devkitPro for ARM use, but I continuously get an error while executing the last two commands. The commands are `make` and `make install`.

The tutorials I am following:

- http://3dbrew.org/wiki/Setting_up_Development_Environment
- http://devkitpro.org/wiki/Getting_Started/devkitARM

When I get to the make command, it gives me this error:

```
/opt/devkitPro/ctrulib/libctru$ sudo make
Makefile:6: *** ***"Please set DEVKITARM in your environment. export DEVKITARM=<path to>devkitARM".  Stop.
```

In the tutorials, it tells me to put that the following commands in my `.bashrc`, so I did, bit it will not work still.

```
export DEVKITPRO=/opt/devkitpro
export DEVKITARM=$DEVKITPRO/devkitARM
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
sudo DEVKITARM=$DEVKITPRO/devkitARM make
```

Though I must say that `make` doesn't usually require `sudo`. You probably need it because you're working off `/opt`, where files are usually owned by root, so it might be simpler to `chown` as neeeded and run just `make`:

```
sudo chown $USER /opt/devkitPro/ -R
```

Comment: I did those commands, and the first one gave me an error back. Am I supposed to do it in a special directory? The second did not give an error, but can you tell me what it did?
bbnorman@bbnorman-Veriton-M460:/opt/devkitPro/ctrulib/libctru$ sudo DEVKITARM=$DEVKITPRO/devkitARM make
Makefile:9: /opt/devkitpro/devkitARM/base_rules: No such file or directory
make: *** No rule to make target `/opt/devkitpro/devkitARM/base_rules'.  Stop.
bbnorman@bbnorman-Veriton-M460:/opt/devkitPro/ctrulib/libctru$ sudo chown $USER /opt/devkitPro/ -R
bbnorman@bbnorman-Veriton-M460:/opt/devkitPro/ctrulib/libctru$

Comment: @Brendon it `ch`anges the `own`er of those files to your user, so that you can modify files without needing `sudo`. As to the error, I think there might be some problem in your `DEVKITARM` path or in your installation of devkitARM. Either way, the variable works fine.

Comment: Okay, should I give you my devkitARM folder location? Maybe you can help me put it in there. Also, should I be editing my .bashrc in home or bash.bashrc in etc?

Comment: @Brendon You have already given the location, haven't you? (`/opt/devkitPro/devkitARM`?) As for setting variables, see: http://askubuntu.com/q/4667/158442

Comment: I will in the meantime. My devkitARM folder location: /opt/devkitPro/devkitARM. The location my environment points to: export DEVKITPRO=/opt/devkitPro
export DEVKITARM=/opt/devkitPro/devkitARM

Comment: I tried make without sudo and it worked. I then switched into root user mode with sudo -s and did the make install. It seems that it is all installed, but I am completely unsure if this was supposed to output a program?

Comment: @Brendon the output of `make install` should be a list of files it copied to some location. You can inspect that to see if a program was created.

Comment: Output:

root@bbnorman-Veriton-M460:/opt/devkitPro/ctrulib/libctru# make install
make[1]: `/opt/devkitPro/ctrulib/libctru/lib/libctru.a' is up to date.
mkdir -p /opt/devkitPro/libctru
bzip2 -cd libctru-0.3.0.tar.bz2 | tar -x -C /opt/devkitPro/libctru

Comment: I suppose I should state this is for 3DS homebrew development in C++. I assumed this all would output some sort of IDE so I could compile my code into a .3DSX, but I suppose not. The creators did not document things all that well. I know it is asking a bit much, but could you try to install it and look around?

Comment: @Brendon The "Setting up .." page mentions Netbeans (which is an IDE), and doesn't talk of any other IDE. `libctru` is, as the name suggests, a library, so it's not surprising nothing runnable was created. You should consider installing a [C++ IDE](http://askubuntu.com/questions/8136/c-programing-suites-ides). I could try, but it would take me a while since I don't have a Linux system on hand.

Comment: @Brendon Also check if there are any 3dsx files in ` /opt/devkitPro/libctru`, where the `make install` command extracted some things to.

Comment: I currently just write C++ in gedit, save as .cpp, and compile through my terminal with the use of g++. Would this allow me to do the same in terminal, but export as a .3DSX? Also, it'd be very appreciated.

Comment: It looks like there is just a million header files in the libctru folder.

Comment: I asked someone on gbatemp, and they said it should not output an IDE, just like you explained to me it would not. They said that I can write it in whatever I choose and make it in the terminal. I'm still a bit lost.